# Python Pandas - use Multiple Character Delimiter when writing to_csv

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, delimiter

It appears that the pandas to_csv function only allows single character delimiters/separators.

Is there some way to allow for a string of characters to be used like, "::" or "%%" instead?

I tried:

```
df.to_csv(local_file,  sep = '::', header=None, index=False)
```

and getting:

```
TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string
```

Comment: You could append to each element a single character of your desired separator and then pass a single character for the delimeter, but if you intend to read this back into `pandas` then you will encounter the same difficulty

Comment: @EdChum Good idea.. What would be a command to append a single character to each field in DF (it has 100 columns and 10000 rows). I am guessing the last column must not have trailing character (because is last). Thanks!

Comment: Do you have some other tool that needs this? Because most spreadsheet programs, Python scripts, R scripts, etc. aren’t going to recognize the format any more than Pandas is.

Comment: Appending the first `:` to each field won’t work, because that just guarantees that every field will get quoted or escaped, so you’re going to get something like `:":"`, or at best`\::`. (And even if you want to force the latter with dialect params, it’s still going to escape every colon it sees in the middle of a value, not just double-colons.)

Comment: ftw, pandas now supports multi-char delimiters. However, if that delimiter shows up in quoted text, it's going to be split on and throw off the true number of fields detected in a line :(

Comment: @AustinA You're talking about `read_csv` which wasn't the problem. As of pandas 2.1 (Sep 2023), `to_csv` still doesn't support multi-char `sep`.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`numpy.savetxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#numpy-savetxt).

Examples:

```
np.savetxt(
    'file.csv',
    np.char.decode(chunk_data.values.astype(np.bytes_), 'UTF-8'),
    delimiter='~|',
    fmt='%s',
    encoding=None)
```

```
np.savetxt(
    'file.dat',
    chunk_data.values,
    delimiter='~|',
    fmt='%s',
    encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: if you're already using dataframes, you can simplify it and even include headers assuming df = pandas.Dataframe: `numpy.savetxt(csv_filepath, df, delimiter=csv_file_delimeter, header=csv_file_delimeter.join(df.columns.values), fmt='%s', comments='', encoding=None) ` (Note the comments='' is needed because otherwise it will automatically prefix a comment symbol in front of the headers)

Comment: thanks @KtMack for the details about the column headers... feels weird to use join here but it works wonderfuly.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what this line `a::b::c‘` means to a standard CSV tool: an `a`, an empty column, a `b`, an empty column, and a `c`. Even in a more complicated case with quoting or escaping:`"abc::def"::2` means an `abc::def`, an empty column, and a 2.

So, all you have to do is add an empty column between every column, and then use `:` as a delimiter, and the output will be almost what you want.

I say “almost” because Pandas is going to quote or escape single colons. Depending on the dialect options you’re using, and the tool you’re trying to interact with, this may or may not be a problem. Unnecessary quoting usually isn’t a problem (unless you ask for `QUOTE_ALL`, because then your columns will be separated by `:"":`, so hopefully you don’t need that dialect option), but unnecessary escapes might be (e.g., you might end up with every single `:` in a string turned into a `\:` or something). So you have to be careful with the options. But it’ll work for the basic “quote as needed, with mostly standard other options” settings.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I am stuck on an old version of pandas. My task was to read a csv with "__" delimiters, clean it to remove personal identifying information, and write the results a new file. I need the result to have the same two-character delimiter.

My preferred solution would have been to convert to numpy and save, like this:

```
df = pandas.read_csv("patient_patient-final.txt", sep="__", engine="python")

# remove personal identifying info from dataframe

massaged = df.drop(['paternal_last', 'maternal_last', 'first', 'middle', 'suffix', 'prefix', 'street1', 'street2', 'phone1', 'phone2', 'email', 'emergencyfullname', 'emergencyphone', 'emergencyemail', 'curp', 'oldid'], axis=1)
np_data = massaged.to_numpy()
np.savetxt("patient_massaged.txt", np_data, fmt="%s", delimiter="__")
```

However, to_numpy() isn't supported in the version of Pandas I have.

So, my fix was to generate a csv with "}" as a temp delimiter, save that to a variable, do a string replace, and write the file myself:

```
df = pandas.read_csv("patient_patient-final.txt", sep="__", engine="python")

# remove personal identifying info from dataframe

massaged = df.drop(['paternal_last', 'maternal_last', 'first', 'middle', 'suffix', 'prefix', 'street1', 'street2', 'phone1', 'phone2', 'email', 'emergencyfullname', 'emergencyphone', 'emergencyemail', 'curp', 'oldid'], axis=1)

x = massaged.to_csv(sep="}", header=False, index=False)
x = x.replace("}", "__")

f=open("patient_massaged.txt", "w")
f.write(x)
f.close()
```