# How do I remove/change header name with Pandas in Python3?

Tags: python, pandas

```
header = "Visited Websites"
bhistory = pd.read_csv('chrome_history.csv', header= None)
print (bhistory[:10][0])
x = bhistory[:10][0]
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
df.to_csv('chrome_history.csv')
```

I wrote this code to output the last 10 website I visited and output it in a csv file. However in the final CSV file, the output is:

```
,0
0,https://datatofish.com/one-python-script-from-another/
1,http://9to5google.com/
2,https://9to5google.com/
3,http://github.com/
4,https://github.com/
5,https://stackoverflow.com/
6,https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow.com&oq=stackoverflow.com+&aqs=chrome..69i58j69i57j0j69i60l3j5i44j69i60.10911j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
7,https://www.reddit.com/
8,http://reddit.com/
9,https://reddit.com/
```

How do I remove or rename `,0` from the first line?

Also how do I add spaces after the row numbers? ie:
from `4,https://github.com/` to >> `4, https://github.com/`

Answer (score 0):

hiii perhaps use `df.to_csv('chrome_history.csv', header=False)`

could use [numpy-savetxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51328454/python-pandas-use-multiple-character-delimiter-when-writing-to-csv) to have a multi-character delimiter

Comment: `header=False` worked however for `sep=', '` I get the error: `"delimiter" must be a 1-character string`. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: i think it only accepts a single char, you could use that numpy-savetxt link perhaps as an alternative.

Comment: `np.savetxt('chrome_history.csv',  delimiter='| ')` I used this but I get the output "Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e| %.18e| %.18e')"