# Pandas in Python 3.8; save dataframe with multi-character delimiter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have Python 3.8. I have to read a csv  in pandas and after some manipulation, write to a new csv. My requirement is that output csv should have multi-character delimiter e.g., ';;;'.
According to my knowledge, multi-char writer csv is not possible in pandas. Isn't it ? how can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Why do you need a multi-char delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Doc https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

sepstr, default ‘,’
String of length 1. Field delimiter for the output file.

Therefore you must look for an alternative like numpy-savetxt from this question.

[Python Pandas - use Multiple Character Delimiter when writing to_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51328454/python-pandas-use-multiple-character-delimiter-when-writing-to-csv)